# Contact form 7 attached email not working well

Tags: wordpress, attachment, email-attachments, contact-form-7

I have this situation, I followed the documentation of contact form 7, so I did.

[file your-file limit:2mb filetypes:doc|docx|jpg|jpeg|pdf]

attached file [your-file] in configuration, so, I do get the email, 
but the the attached file comes like the picture.

[image: This is how the attached file looks like in the email]

any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: You want to upload pdf file and upload from form fields.

Comment: the upload works fine, the <input > is showing accepting the format PDF, but I receive the email like the image above. I tried other formats like JPG and DOCX, all the same, two servers host end the same, I have no Ideia What I am doing wrong

Comment: @PPL Fixed using Gmail SMTP.